# Test for the number of mutations in DNA strings

Tags: algorithm, difference, levenshtein-distance, dna-sequence

I have a function which takes two strings representing DNA (Of the form `"ACGT"`) with each letter representing a different base. I would like to test for the number of mutations that have needed to occur for one to become the other.

The types of mutations that I want to consider are:

- Substitution: where one base is replaced with another
- Insertion: where a base is inserted into a sequence
- Deletion: where a base is removed from a sequence

I can get each of these three things working individually, but the problem that I'm facing is being able to test for all three at once.

For example, the code I've written to test for substitutions, will count all bases in the event of a  insertion/deletion mutation.

What sort of algorithm would I need to be able to find the minimum number of mutations to go between two DNA sequences?

Comment: Search for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

Comment: @MrSmith42 thank you, I didn't know what to look for, this seems to be exactly what I need :)

Comment: @MrSmith42 You should make that an answer so the OP can mark it as accepted and then others will that it has an answer. Also my first computer was an Atari 800. :)

Comment: @Guy Coder: My first computer was an Atari ST 520. I still love the old computers. You could now every bit of hardware and access it directly without tons of abstraction layers in your way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of different is called 'edit-distance'

It can be calculated by dynamic programming:

For more details how to implement it see:

[edit distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)

This secific edit-distance is also known as [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) (You can find sample code: [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance))